# How to set decimal precision in shapefile via javacode

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools

we are using the below code :

```
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName("Location");

    String wkt =  "GEOGCS[" + "\"GCS_WGS_1984\"," + "  DATUM[" + "    \"D_WGS_1984\","
    + "    SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137,298.257223563]],"
    + "  PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],"
    + "  UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],"
    + "  AXIS[\"Lat\",NORTH]," + "  AXIS[\"Long\",EAST],"
    + "  AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]";


    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.parseWKT(wkt);      
    System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");
    builder.setCRS(crs);


    builder.add("the_geom", Point.class);

    builder.length(15).add("ID", Long.class); 
    builder.length(4).add("FEATTYP",Integer.class);
    builder.length(1).add("IMPORT",Integer.class);
    builder.length(3).add("ARNAMELC",String.class);
    builder.length(240).add("NAME",String.class);
    builder.length(150).add("STNAME",String.class);
    builder.length(3).add("STNAMELC",String.class);
    builder.length(15).add("HSNUM",String.class); 
    builder.length(10).add("POSTCODE",String.class);
    builder.length(15).add("MUNID",Long.class);
    builder.length(11).add("MUNCD",String.class);
    builder.length(100).add("MUNNAME",String.class);
    builder.length(100).add("BUANAME",String.class);
    builder.length(25).add("TELNUM",String.class);
    builder.length(25).add("FAXNUM",String.class);
    builder.length(70).add("EMAIL",String.class);
    builder.length(150).add("HTTP",String.class);
    builder.length(70).add("COMPNAME",String.class);
    builder.length(15).add("CLTRPELID",Long.class);
    builder.length(6).add("RELPOS",Double.class);
    builder.length(50).add("EXTPOIID",String.class);
    builder.length(15).add("ADDRPID",Long.class);
    builder.length(7).add("SUBCAT",Long.class);
    builder.length(2).add("GAL",Integer.class);
    builder.length(1).add("POSACCUR",Integer.class);

    final SimpleFeatureType LOCATION = builder.buildFeatureType();
    return LOCATION;
}
```

I need decimal precision value in RELPOS column as XXXXXX.XXX (6,3). how can i do from java code can any one suggest

Comment: You had an `ArcGIS` tag on this but it looks more like [tag:geotools] code.  If you are using a product from the ArcGIS platform to try and do this then can you edit your question to clarify which one, please?

Comment: yes this code is from geotools code, but how to set precision kindly let me know

Answer (score 1):

A generic Java answer is: Use the `BigDecimal` class.

Hope this will work with your specific implementation too...

Comment: but one thing i want to define decimal precision of 3 how can i set this, as in BigDecimal class is showing error message when we are defining as like : builder.length(6,3).add("RELPOS",BigDecimal.class);

Comment: According to the builder API, `length` only takes one argument. Anyways, it may not be possible at all... at least since 2011: http://sourceforge.net/p/geotools/mailman/message/28217887/ . Try cross-referencing some more on Google or wait for another response... sorry.

Comment: waiting for another response.......

Comment: Can anyone help me how to set user defined decimal precision in perticular field of ShapeFile